# Using javascript to alter span text dynamically and keeping the original text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  html page, inside which i have following code snippet, depending on which case we're following:

```
CASE 1)    <p> <span id ="xyz">  some code here  </span> </p>
CASE 2)    <p> <span id ="xyz">   </span> some code here </p>
```

Now in my javascript code I have to write values in span `xyz` dynamically. If I try to do get reference to span `xyz` by id and then try to alter its innerHTML, then the html already present in span `xyz` is lost.

If I keep extra code outside the span, it appears on new line due to some css effects. I cannot alter css due to some reasons.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  One thing I will note: do not use the same "id" value on more than one element.  (I can't even tell if that's what you're doing, however.)

Comment: i just mentioned 2 possible ways 2 do it , and problem am facing with each approach

Answer (score 3):

You can just store the current value in a String, and then modify this string:

```
var mySpan = document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML;
mySpan += ' and this gets added after the some code here';
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = mySpan;
```

or faster and more shorthand,

```
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML + ' new text after'; //to add text after the existing text
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = 'your new text before ' + document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML; //to add text before.
```

Comment: just a slight fix to this solution is that innerHTML is property and not a function. So you have to get rid of the parentheses and capitalize the HTML part.

Comment: @Dan thanks - jQuery's `html()` always makes me do that to old javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

You can append a new text node to span, if you want to keep the old text.

```
var newtext = document.createTextNode(" new text ");
var spanXyz = document.getElementById("xyz");
spanXyz.appendChild(newtext);
```

Refer these: [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

**Edit**: To add new text at the beginning, you can use something like

```
spanXyz.textContent = "new text " + spanXyz.textContent;
```

Comment: +1: I like this way, but I would perhaps make a one-liner out of it: `document.getElementById("xyz").appendChild(document.createTextNode(" new text "));`

Comment: Yeah, I was just spelling it out for the OP.

Comment: thanks.I liked this approach, but the text i want to appent shold appear at begening of span not end.Eg if span consist of text B then i want to make it AB.This is just a eg.I actually have some html code as A and B

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using jquery :

```
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML=   document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML + "XYZ";
```

If you are using jquery:

```
 $("#xyz").append("xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = 'some code here' + 'dynamically code';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = 'dynamically code' + 'some code here' ;
```